# How to change radius of drawn ellipse in p5.js?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I've been learning how to use the p5.js library and got stuck when making a simple sketch. The goal of the code is to have a slider that changes the radius of the drawn ellipse. The slider works when increasing the value, but when decreasing it, the biggest ellipse that was drawn covers up the smaller ones. This makes sense, as an ellipse is constantly being drawn. But is there a way to have just 1 ellipse and change its radius with the slider?

Here's the awful code I managed to put together that works.
JS:

```js
var spr;
var slider;
function setup() {
  createCanvas(500,500);
  background(51);
  spr = new Sphere();
  slider = createSlider(0, width, 1);
  slider.position(6, 6);
  slider.style('width','500px');
}

function draw() {
  var val = slider.value();
  spr.show(val);
}

function Sphere() {
  this.x = width/2;
  this.y = height/2;

  this.show = function(val){
    noStroke();
    fill(100,0,250);
    ellipse(this.x, this.y, val, val);
  }
}
```

[Here is a picture of how it looks like in the browser.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShjcT.png)

Before asking, I'd searched for an answer but couldn't find one. It's probably really simple and I've just missed something very important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're never clearing out old frames, so everything you draw stays on the screen. That's why your largest drawing is always covering up your smaller drawings.

To clear out old screens, just add a call to the `background()` function as the first line in the `draw()` function.

More info can be found in [the reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/background).

Comment: Thank you! This fixed the problem.